# Secret_Key setting must nor be Empty Error?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, secret-key

While running my project in terminal, after running the command:

```
python manage.py build -ad
```

I am getting this following error. Can anyone help me out

```
(project1) srk@srk-Lenovo-G580:~/easygaadi_backend$ python manage.py runserver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 306, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 229, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 223, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 156, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/srk/Envs/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__



    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: check your `settings.py` file and make sure there is a `SECRET_KEY = <some string>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET\_KEY setting must not be empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty) and [The secret key setting must not be empty available at settings.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457665/)

Comment: Secret key = :)    from __future__ import absolute_import

"""
Django settings for easygaadi_backend project.

"""
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ..)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
# Please Do not forget to change this secret key.
SECRET_KEY = ':('

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_zappa',